# Elvang and Huang sign error? Polarization Vectors in the Spinor Helicity Formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors, helicity

I am reading through [Elvang and Huang's](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697) treatment of polarization vectors for all outgoing spin-1 massless particles (metric signature $(-,+,+,+)$).

It is given in Eq. (2.50) in the PDF (but Eq. (2.51) in the textbook version) that the polarization for a particle of momentum $p$, reference spinor $q \neq p$, can be written as

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\not \varepsilon_{+}(p ; q)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\langle q p\rangle}(|p]\langle q|+| q\rangle[p |)
\end{equation}

for plus-helicity, and

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\not \varepsilon_{-}(p ; q)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{[q p]}(|p\rangle[q|+| q]\langle p|)
\end{equation}

for minus helicity.

However, my understanding is that polarization vectors of opposite helicity should be related by complex conjugation; namely, $\left(\varepsilon_{+}\right)^{*}=\varepsilon_{-}$.

I don't see how $(1)$ and $(2)$ satisfy this property. The authors give that $[p|=(|p\rangle)^{*}$ and $\left\langle\left. p\right|=(| p]\right)^{*}$, as well as the antisymmetry property $\langle p q\rangle=-\langle q p\rangle, [p q]=-[q p]$. It therefore seems to me that one of $(1)$ and $(2)$ should have a minus sign out front to satisfy the property $\left(\varepsilon_{+}\right)^{*}=\varepsilon_{-}$.

I suspect that things are more complicated because the polarization vectors in $(1)$ and $(2)$ are contracted with $\gamma^\mu$, but I don't know of a simple relationship for $(\gamma^\mu)^*$.

Comment: Your understanding is not correct. It’s a convention.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Prahar. Just to clarify, are you saying that it is convention to take the polarization vectors as complex conjugates of each other?

Comment: That's correct. Polarizations are only defined up to additive shifts, $\epsilon^\mu \to \epsilon^\mu + \lambda(p) p^\mu$ where $\lambda(p)$ is any function of the momentum, including complex functions. Elvang-Huang are just using a different convention - one that is perhaps more useful for their purposes.

Comment: You can see eq. (2.51) in their notes where the explicitly write out their polarizations.